# Fossil: repository does not exist or is in an unreadable directory?

Tags: fossil

I have 2 local repos on my notebook.
The first one is Fresh.fossil (`http://chiselapp.com/user/johnfound/repository/FreshIDE/`), located in `C:\FASM\STUFFS`, and the second one is book.fossil (`http://clone:clone255@www.fossil-scm.org/schimpf-book book.fossil`), located in `C:\Downloads\Software`.

I'd like to update the second one, so first I did was `fossil open book.fossil`, and and error occured:

> C:\Downloads\software\fossil.exe: repository does not exist or is in an unreadable directory: C :/Downloads/software/Fresh.fossil

This error didn't occured when I updated the first repo. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

This is likely because repository was moved since it was opened for a first time.
Fossil remember where repository was opened, but no longer able to find it at the expected location.

When relocating repository you need to do the following (in the source tree):

```
rm _FOSSIL_
fossil open repo-file-name.fossil --keep
```

Comment: I got the same error as OP, not for moving the repository, as it had been created seconds earlier, more like a bug or something. Removing _FOSSIL_ as you suggest, and running "fossil all rebuild" did the trick. But fossil open etc. keep didn't help. Thanks for the tips Onlyjob.

Comment: The local repository could also be called `.fslckout` or `.fos`.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this email](http://lists.fossil-scm.org:8080/pipermail/fossil-users/2013-October/014470.html) and get the solution:

```
rm YouCloneDirectory/.fslckout
```

Have a good day.